# How can I create an folder using PHP with the name based on the input of an HTML Form?

Tags: php

I would like to create a folder using PHP with the name based on the input value of an HTML form.

Μy html code is as follows:

```
<input  name="foldername" id="foldername" >
```

While the PHP I have is as follows:

```php
if (isset($_POST['createDir'])) {
    //get value of inputfield
    $dir = $_POST['dirname'];
    //set the target path ??
    $targetfilename = PATH . '/' . $dir;
    if (!file_exists($dir)) {
        mkdir($dir); //create the directory
        chmod($targetfilename, 0777); //make it writable
    }
}
```

My code doesn't seem to function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This scares me that you're not validating the `$dir` variable at all, but try this: `mkdir($dir, 0777, true);` (and you can remove the `chmod` line)

Comment: Agreed - validating the input is also important.

Answer (score 3):

The name of your input is "foldername" but in the PHP you refer to "dirname" - these need to be the same.

Comment: Oh, I missed that.  You mean `$targetfilename`?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify.

As it stands now, $dir is equal to $_POST['dirname']. The problem is that the POST variable 'dirname' doesn't exist. In your HTML you name your input "foldername." So, in your PHP you need to access it by $_POST['foldername'].

var_dump($_POST) to get a better look at what exactly is coming into the POST variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// You are passing in a hidden field or something for this, right?
if (isset($_POST['createDir']) and ! empty($_POST['foldername']) 
{
    $dir  = $_POST['foldername']; // This must match the "name" of your input
    $path = PATH . '/' . $dir;
    is_dir($path) or mkdir($path, 0777, true);
}

print_r($_POST); exit; // just so we can help you debug a little...
```